# Adding extension attribute to customer in GraphQL Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, extension-attributes, graphql

In magento2 - I have created one extension attribute for customer using plugin, it's working fine for Rest API also. How can I include this extension attribute in **GraphQL**?

In `createCustomer` mutation , all the `CustomerInput` are added. Can anyone help me in adding an extension attribute to this mutation?

Comment: Did you try to pass that attribute in the CustomerInput, i am asking this based on the product Attribute, If we create a custom product attribute we can get the value by just passing the attribute_code in the query.

Comment: How can I extend the CustomerInput in vendor ?

Comment: Can you just elaborate on this?

Comment: you just pass your new attribute in CustomerInput and see, but currently CustomerInput only have  prefix,firstname,middlename,lastname,suffix,email,dob,taxvat,gender,password,is_subscribed fields.if passing the attribute to the mutation not work you have to write your own module to add the attribute and do some work arround in Magento\\CustomerGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\CreateCustomer in your own module.

Comment: study the module-customer-graph-ql in vendor/magento directory.

Comment: I have checked module-customer-graph-ql in vendor/magento, but how can I pass extension attibute to CustomerInput or do I need to create a new mutation

Comment: We can directly add mutation in custom module with the same name. Add proper resolver for extension attribute.

Comment: kindly answer your approach please

Answer (score 4):

**Magento 2.4**

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
type Customer {
  sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Customer Custom Attribute Show")
    @resolver(
      class: "\\VendoreName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\GetCustomerCustomAttr"
    )
}

input CustomerInput {
  sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Customer Custom Attribute Val")
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver**

**GetCustomerCustomAttr.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

/**
 * Customer custom attribute field resolver
 */
class GetCustomerCustomAttr implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        if (!isset($value['model'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
        }
        /** @var CustomerInterface $customer */
        $customer = $value['model'];
        $customerId = (int) $customer->getId();
        $customerData = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);

        /* Get customer custom attribute value */
        if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attributess')) {
            $customerAttributeVal = $customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attributess')->getValue();
        } else {
            $customerAttributeVal = null;
        }

        return $customerAttributeVal;
    }
}
```

> **Get customer custom attribute value**

```
{
  customer {
    email
    sample_attribute
  }
}
```

> **Update customer custom attribute value**

```
mutation {
  updateCustomer(
    input: {
      firstname: "Rob",
      sample_attribute: "Text"
    }
  ) {
    customer {
      firstname
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @msquare, how to use this in createCustomer mutation. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365787/createcustomer-mutation-with-custom-attribute-in-magento2

Answer (score 2):

For fetching custom attributes data in your customer graphql api you just need to add the attribute into your schema.graphqls file in following way

```
  type Customer 
{
    mobile_number: String
    customer_city: String
    customer_state: String
    customer_country: String
}
```

and pass query as

```
{
  customer {
    firstname
    lastname
    email
    mobile_number
    customer_city
    customer_state
    customer_country
  }
  
}
```

It will automatically fetch your custom attributes data.

Hope this helps you.

Thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is re-define the '**CustomerInput**' parameter (with your custom extension attribute) of the createCustomer mutation.

In your module's **schema.graphqls file**, re-define the '**CustomerInput**' type.

```
input CustomerInput {
    your_extention_attr: String
}
```

Then run the below commands.

`rm -rf generation/`

`bin/magento c:f`

Now you can parse this new parameter in createCuatomer mutation. See the example below.

```
mutation {
  createCustomer(
    input: {
      firstname: "Bob"
      lastname: "Loblaw"
      email: "bobldsdd2@example.com"
      password: "b0bl0bl@w"
      is_subscribed: true
      your_extention_attr: "this is a test value"
    }
  ) {
    customer {
      id
      firstname
      lastname
      email
      is_subscribed
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this way not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

in your schema.graphqls use interface
eg I have added these customer attributes

```
 interface createCustomer{
    mobile_no: String
        @doc(description: "Name of attribute set assigned to the product")
        @resolver(class: "\\CompanyName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\CreateCustomer"),
    b2b_category: String
        @doc(description: "Name of attribute set assigned to the product")
        @resolver(class: "\\CompanyName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\CreateCustomer"),
    gstin: String
        @doc(description: "Name of attribute set assigned to the product")
        @resolver(class: "\\CompanyName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\CreateCustomer"),
    customer_code: String
        @doc(description: "Name of attribute set assigned to the product")
        @resolver(class: "\\CompanyName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\CreateCustomer"),
    customer_discount_rate: String
        @doc(description: "Name of attribute set assigned to the product")
        @resolver(class: "\\CompanyName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\CreateCustomer")
}

input CustomerInput {
    mobile_no: String
    b2b_category: String
    gstin: String
    customer_code: String
    customer_discount_rate: String
}
```

Now create a file CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver\CreateCustomer.php
in your CreateCustomer.php create CreateCustomer class