# add custom attribute to customer in graphql magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, customer, graphql

my custom module

schema.graphql

```
input CustomerInput {
    sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "new attribute")
}
```

> but not adding this attribute in customer mutation
>
> magento 2 graphql
>
> I created a custom attribute in Magento backend for Customers

*sample_attribute*

> I tried this answer [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/296842/73525)

how I can solve this??

Comment: you can check my answer as I done this today 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/352171/82482

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 2.4**

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
type Customer {
  sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Customer Custom Attribute Show")
    @resolver(
      class: "\\VendoreName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\GetCustomerCustomAttr"
    )
}

input CustomerInput {
  sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Customer Custom Attribute Val")
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver**

**GetCustomerCustomAttr.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

/**
 * Customer custom attribute field resolver
 */
class GetCustomerCustomAttr implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        if (!isset($value['model'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
        }
        /** @var CustomerInterface $customer */
        $customer = $value['model'];
        $customerId = (int) $customer->getId();
        $customerData = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);

        /* Get customer custom attribute value */
        if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attributess')) {
            $customerAttributeVal = $customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attributess')->getValue();
        } else {
            $customerAttributeVal = null;
        }

        return $customerAttributeVal;
    }
}
```

> **Get customer custom attribute value**

```
{
  customer {
    email
    sample_attribute
  }
}
```

> **Update customer custom attribute value**

```
mutation {
  updateCustomer(
    input: {
      firstname: "Rob",
      sample_attribute: "Text"
    }
  ) {
    customer {
      firstname
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are trying to return a new attribute (a custom one) via customer GQL query. The below answer is based on that.

Below is the sample code of adding a custom attribute to Customer GraphQl query.

Module NameSpace : Kcc
Module Name : CustomerGraphQl

`app/code/Kcc/CustomerGraphQl/etc/schema.graphqls`

```
type Customer {
    sample_attribute: String @resolver(class: "Kcc\\CustomerGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\Sample")
}
```

The resolver class
`app/code/Kcc/CustomerGraphQl/Model/Resolver/Sample.php`

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Kcc\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory as BestSellersCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class Sample implements ResolverInterface
{
    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        // Return the value of sample_attribute here.
        return 'My sample attr value';
    }
}
```

When you run the customer query, it should return the new attribute if requested.
[image]

Comment: let me check and inform you.....

Comment: that's one not working....

Comment: actually I want to add a custom attribute in Createcustomer - mutation

Comment: the issue is to add extra input argument not output