# How to change custom customer attributes with GraphQL mutation?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer, magento-graphql

I followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353492/96355) answer to create a custom attribute on customer with graphQL. The query works great, but if I try to change the value with a mutation, it just returns null. Can anyone please help me with adding this functionality please? Code and example below:

schema.graphql:

```
type Customer {
  sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Customer Custom Attribute Show")
    @resolver(
      class: "\\Wrightway\\CustomGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\GetCustomerCustomAttr"
    )
}

input CustomerInput {
  sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Customer Custom Attribute Val")
}
```

Model/Resolver/GetCustomerCustomAttr.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace Wrightway\CustomGraphQl\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

/**
 * Customer custom attribute field resolver
 */
class GetCustomerCustomAttr implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        if (!isset($value['model'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
        }
        /** @var CustomerInterface $customer */
        $customer = $value['model'];
        $customerId = (int) $customer->getId();
        $customerData = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);

        /* Get customer custom attribute value */
        if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attributess')) {
            $customerAttributeVal = $customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attributess')->getValue();
        } else {
            $customerAttributeVal = null;
        }

        return $customerAttributeVal;
    }
}
```

Query example (works great):

```
{
  customer {
    firstname
    sample_attribute
  }
}
```

returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "customer": {
      "firstname": "Adam",
      "sample_attribute": null
    }
  }
}
```

Mutation example (doesn't work, returns null when attempted to change data):

```
mutation {
  updateCustomer(
    input: {
      firstname: "Adam",
      sample_attribute: "This is sample text"
    }
  ) {
    customer {
      firstname
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

returns (The added data, "This is sample text" returns null, and also returns null on the query.:

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateCustomer": {
      "customer": {
        "firstname": "Adam",
        "sample_attribute": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What do I need to add to make this work? Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written an example that interacts with 2 extension attributes. One is called `preferred_colour` and it does the same thing as your `sample_attribute` extension attribute

My graphql is like below:

```
type Customer {    
    preferred_colour: String
        @doc(description: "Customer Preferred Colour")
        @resolver(class: "\\Mbs\\CustomerAttribute\\Model\\Resolver\\GetCustomerPreferredColour")
}

input CustomerInput {
    preferred_colour: String
}
```

You need a customer repository plugin like below

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="save_additional_customer_info" type="Mbs\CustomerAttribute\Plugin\AssignAdditionalData" />
    </type>
```

I add below the plugin code

```
class AssignAdditionalData
{
    private \Mbs\CustomerAttribute\Model\AdditionalCustomerInfoHandler $additionalCustomerInfoHandler;

    /**
     * @param AdditionalCustomerInfoHandler $additionalCustomerInfoHandler
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Mbs\CustomerAttribute\Model\AdditionalCustomerInfoHandler $additionalCustomerInfoHandler
    ) {
        $this->additionalCustomerInfoHandler = $additionalCustomerInfoHandler;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
    ) {
        $this->addAdditionalInfoExtensionAttribute($customer);
        return $customer;
    }

    public function afterGetList(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerSearchResultsInterface $results
    ) {
        array_map([$this, 'addAdditionalInfoExtensionAttribute'], $results->getItems());
        return $results;
    }

    ..
}
```

As you can see the plugin hydrates the customer data from the extension attributes data

I add the url to a public repository so that you can see the full code.

[customer attribute repository](https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/customer-attribute/src/master). Particularly, within this code, the class `\Mbs\CustomerAttribute\Model\AdditionalCustomerInfoHandler` is what you may want to take a look at.

Comment: Thank you, this is a huge help!

Comment: my pleasure, feel free to thumb up it, it will give me 10 more points :-)