# createCustomer mutation with custom attribute in magento2

Tags: magento2, graphql, create-account

I Have created a module to add custom attribute to createCustomer mutation.

**Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
    <attribute code="custom_attr" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensionAttributesObjects" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_attr" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionInterface</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionInterface.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Api\Data;

interface CustomerExtensionInterface
 {
/**
 * Get customAttr
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getCustomAttr(): ?string;

/**
 * Set custom_attr
 *
 * @param string|null $custom_attr
 * @return $this
 */
 public function setCustomAttr(?string $custom_attr): self;
 }
```

Now I am trying this request in createCustomer Mutattion

```
mutation {
  createCustomer(
    input: {
     firstname: "test"
     lastname: "test"
     email: "test@gmail.com.com"
     is_subscribed: true
     custom_attr: "test value"
   }
 ) {
    customer {
     id
     firstname
     lastname
     email
    }
  }
 }
```

**Note:** created the "**custom_attr**" customer attribute with data patch.

Getting below error

"message": "Field "custom_attr" is not defined by type CustomerInput.",

Can someone help me on this how to custom attribute in the create customer mutation in graphQL.

Answer (score 0):

To extend existed GraphQL schema you need to redefine the needed type/interface/input like we do with XML schema in Magento.

First things first you should create the `schema.graphqls` file in your custom module under `etc` directory.

In this file you need to redefine the CustomerInput input type (your custom input option will be merged with already defined input options in Magento):

> If you are using Magento version 2.4.6 please replace `CustomerInput` with `CustomerCreateInput` and for mutation use `createCustomerV2`

```
input CustomerInput {
    custom_attr: String
}
```